# Making form useable during a function C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, youtube, backgroundworker

I'm having trouble running a function on another thread, I've tried BackgroundWorked as well as System.Threading methods.

The function simply does not start if using any of those, and without those, it freezes the form for a couple of seconds till the work is complete.

It is a youtube downloader, using a lib that gets the info from youtube.

I have a VideoItem class, which inside has one array that holds all the qualities of videos and there links. Populating that takes another 10 secs or so.

In my main form, there is a function that creates a new VideoInfo instance, when user presses a button

```
    public void addURLfromClipboard()
    {
        string clipboardURL = Clipboard.GetText();
        VideoItem _item;
        if (clipboardURL.StartsWith("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=") ||                clipboardURL.StartsWith("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="))
        {
            DownloadUrlResolver.OnDownloadProgressChanged += DownloadUrlResolver_OnDownloadProgressChanged;
            videosProcessing++;
            progressbar.Enabled = true;

            _item = new VideoItem(clipboardURL);
            if (listYoutube.FindItemByVideo(_item) == null) listYoutube.AddItem(_item);
            videosProcessing--;
            if (videosProcessing == 0) progressbar.Enabled = false;

        }

        else return;
    }
```

How do i go about making the form responsive during that function call?

Answer (score 1):

if you wrap the whole function body in a `Task.Factory.StartNew( () => { body here });` it should return immediately.

Comment: maybe not the function body in the Task but calling the function from inside the Task +1 anyways cheers!